# Coding exercises list

Tags: python-3.x

I’m doing an exercise for a service I use and got thrown a TypeError for this code:

```
class_name_test = [['Jenny', 90], ['Alexus', 85.5], ['Sam', 83], ['Ellie', 101.5] ['Bod', 29340]]
print(class_name_test[0] [2])
```

The error only appeared after I added Bod and the number after Bod which I added at the same time since I’m having a little trouble understanding some wired part of lists. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
class_name_test = [['Jenny', 901,
['Alexus', 85.51, ['Sam', 831, I'Ellie', 101.5] I'Bod', 29340]] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I haven’t tried anything since I have absolutely no idea what’s wrong.

Comment: After testing some things it appears that It throws the error only once I add ‘Bod’ so I guess it is either I did something wrong with how I added the name or it is a problem with the service. Or I just haven’t seen something simple.

Comment: I figured out the error… I was missing a comma.